# Rails strong parameters for infinitely nestable model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have a model, QueryElement, with a child class, QueryGroup.
QueryGroup can contain nested QueryElements.

Say QueryGroup has a propertyname, and QueryElement has a property filter (just for example)

So for strong parameters I have something like:

```
params.fetch(:query).permit(:name, :filter, :query_elements => [:name, :filter, :query_elements => [...]
```

And so on.

I could permit all (defeating the security of strong parameters, which I'd rather avoid), or manually step through the tree, which is much slower. That's my current approach.

Is there a better way?

Comment: what do you mean, "much slower"?

Comment: These objects tend to get nested very deep, so stepping through these large trees for every request isn't ideal

Comment: How do you think the whitelisting would work? Stepping through the structure is unavoidable.

Comment: Alright granted, but can we ignore the performance thing for a second? I would still like a cleaner approach

Comment: I imagine a recursive filter function would work just fine. Custom, using `Hash#slice` (or something), not strong params

Comment: A cleaner approach at something which just screams horrible anti-pattern...

Comment: @max: sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do :) Not all applications fit the patterns.

Comment: Actually it's called the composite pattern, and it underlies how filesystems work

Comment: You might want to allow a maximum depth in your nesting, and as @SergioTulentsev said, a recursive function that could maybe use Strong Parameters or a combination of `Hash#slice`(= allow)/`Hash#fetch_values`(=required) which should be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
REQUIRED = %i( name ).freeze
ALLOWED = (%i( filter query_elements ) + REQUIRED).freeze
MAX_DEPTH = 5

def ensure_params(hash, nest_level = 0) # ah I never come up with good names...
  raise 'you went too deep man' if nest_level > MAX_DEPTH
  hash.fetch_values(*REQUIRED)
  hash[:query_elements] = ensure_params(hash[:query_elements], nest_level + 1) if hash[:query_elements]
  hash.slice(*ALLOWED)
end
```

In IRB:

```
> ensure_params({ :filter => 2, :name => 'test', unpermitted_param: :something, :query_elements => { filter: 3, name: 'test', nested_unpermitted: 13 } })
# => {:filter=>2, :query_elements=>{:filter=>3, :name=>"test"}, :name=>"test"} 
> ensure_params({ name: 1, query_elements: { notname: 1 } })
KeyError: key not found: :name
> MAX_DEPTH = 3
# => 3 
> ensure_params({ name: 1, query_elements: { name: 1, query_elements: { name: 1, query_elements: { name: 1, query_elements: { name: 1, query_elements: { name: 1 } } } } }})
RuntimeError: you went too deep man
```

There is probably some improvements that could be done, like converting the keys to symbols, have a better error message to tell you at which nest level there is a missing key, etc.